# JSON Build Object removes trailing 0 in timestamp with timezone

Tags: python, postgresql

Whenever a timestamp with timezone end with a 0 in the milliseconds, the last 0 is removed when performing JSON_BUILD_OBJECT.

I am creating a json object like so:

```
RETURN (
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'log_entries',
        (SELECT JSON_AGG(logs)
         FROM (
                  SELECT log_id
                         last_activity_time,  -- this is the timestamp
```

If I select the column and return without creating a json, the timestamp value in the retuned table is:

```
2021-02-11 18:06:21.511490 +00:00
```

If returning a JSON, it is :

```
"2021-02-11T18:06:21.51149+00:00"
```

How can I keep the last "0" after the 9?

EDIT:

Python code that breaks without all 6 ms digits ( if the trailing 0's get truncated):

```
    time_format = "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M %Z"

    utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp_utc)

    # convert to a pytz timezone object
    new_timezone = pytz.timezone(time_zone)

    # adjust timezone
    new_timezone_datetime = utc_datetime.astimezone(new_timezone)

    return new_timezone_datetime.strftime(time_format)
```

Comment: I'm curious what you're doing with the "regular select". If I do a select * on a table with a timestamptz column I'm seeing it drop the trailing zeros as well - no JSON involved.

Comment: @RichardWheeldon in both cases, it is a query that is returned by a function. Either returning the table columns does not drop the 0, or returning as a json, which does. I tried select * from the table and 0 was not dropped for me. This seems to only happen when creating a json. Maybe because the value is turned into a string. I'm not sure. I'm on postgres 11.8

Comment: Why do you want to keep the `0`? It is meaningless. But if you really want to control the format use `to_char()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i just found your SO post saying to do that and it worked. The reason the 0 is needed is because we store all timestamps in UTC and then do conversion to a different time zone as needed. Without all 6 ms digits, I get a "invalid isoformat string" error. I added the python code that breaks to the post,  if trailing 0s are missing.

Comment: BTW "datetime.fromisoformat(date_string) ... **Caution**: This does _not_ support parsing arbitrary ISO 8601 strings - it is only intended as the inverse operation of [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat). A more full-featured ISO 8601 parser, `dateutil.parser.isoparse` is available in the third-party package [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse)." https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep the 0, just format around it:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = "2021-02-11T18:06:21.51149+00:00" 
input_format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
datetime.strptime(dt, input_format)

datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 11, 18, 6, 21, 511490, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```